# AdamW and Adam with weight decay

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Is there any difference between `torch.optim.Adam(weight_decay=0.01)` and `torch.optim.AdamW(weight_decay=0.01)`?

Link to the docs: [torch.optim](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, Adam and AdamW weight decay are different.

> Hutter pointed out in their paper ([Decoupled Weight Decay Regularization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05101)) that the way weight decay is implemented in Adam in every library seems to be wrong, and proposed a simple way (which they call AdamW) to fix it.

In Adam, the weight decay is usually implemented by adding `wd*w` (`wd` is weight decay here) to the gradients (Ist case), rather than actually subtracting from weights (IInd case).

```
# Ist: Adam weight decay implementation (L2 regularization)
final_loss = loss + wd * all_weights.pow(2).sum() / 2
# IInd: equivalent to this in SGD
w = w - lr * w.grad - lr * wd * w
```

> These methods are same for vanilla SGD, but as soon as we add momentum, or use a more sophisticated optimizer like Adam, L2 regularization (first equation) and weight decay (second equation) become different.

AdamW follows the second equation for weight decay.

In Adam

> weight_decay (float, optional) – weight decay (L2 penalty) (default: 0)

In AdamW

> weight_decay (float, optional) – weight decay coefficient (default: 1e-2)

Read more on the [fastai blog](https://www.fast.ai/2018/07/02/adam-weight-decay/).

Comment: Just to add to that, there seems to be a somehow misleading statement in the documentation of torch.optim.adam at the moment, (wrongly) suggesting that Adam is also using the newer version of weight-decay, which would make it equivalent to AdamW. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/48793
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/50464

Comment: sooooooo.... use AdamW basically?

Answer (score 9):

In **Pytorch**, the implementations of Adam and AdamW are different. In the [Adam source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cb2337326407a39efbb2a0d1faa7a1146ad68529/torch/optim/adam.py#L351-L352), weight decay is implemented as

```py
grad = grad.add(param, alpha=weight_decay)
```

whereas in the [AdamW source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cb2337326407a39efbb2a0d1faa7a1146ad68529/torch/optim/adamw.py#L401), it is implemented as

```py
param.mul_(1 - lr * weight_decay)
```

So in each iteration, in Adam, the *gradient* is updated by the estimated parameters from the previous iteration weighted by the weight decay. On the other hand, in AdamW, the *parameters* are updated by the parameters from the previous iteration weighted by the weight decay. The pseudocode from the documentation clearly shows the difference (*boxed for emphasis*) where lambda is the weight decay.

[image: pseudocode]

---

However in **Keras**, even thought the default implementations are different because Adam has `weight_decay=None` while AdamW has `weight_decay=0.004` (in fact, it cannot be None), if `weight_decay` is not None, Adam is the same as AdamW. Both are subclassed from `optimizer.Optimizer` and in fact, their source codes are almost identical; in particular, the variables updated in each iteration are the same. The only difference is that the definition of [Adam's](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3ffea6602dbbb481e82312baa24fe657de83e11/keras/optimizers/adam.py#L110) `weight_decay` is deferred to the parent class while [AdamW's](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3ffea6602dbbb481e82312baa24fe657de83e11/keras/optimizers/adamw.py#L117) `weight_decay` is defined in the AdamW class itself.

Comment: This is interesting. So in PyTorch, they are different, but in Keras, they are the same

Comment: Does this mean that in the event of weight_decay=0, the optimizers are equivalent?

Comment: @StefanTodoran for keras yes, for pytorch no.